# How does std::conditional_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, TypeWhenTrue, TypeWhenFalse> determine how to evaluate?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

It seems that std::conditional_t<B,T,F> doesn't always return the second value, even when B is false.  Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using UnderlyingType = std::conditional_t< std::is_enum_v<T>, std::underlying_type_t<T>, T >;

template< typename T >
constexpr UnderlyingType<T> toUnderlying( T val )
{
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_enum_v<T>, "T must be an enum, or an integral type" );
    return val;
}

enum ExampleEnum {
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

int main()
{
    UnderlyingType<ExampleEnum> underlying = toUnderlying( ZERO ); // compiles and works fine
    UnderlyingType<ExampleEnum> actual = toUnderlying( 0 ); // error: no matching function for call to 'toUnderlying(int)'
}
```

Then later on in the error message I get:

```cpp
<source>:4:7: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::underlying_type<int>'
    4 | using UnderlyingType = std::conditional_t< std::is_enum_v<T>, std::underlying_type_t<T>, T >;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here's the code in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/zd5qT94qY

Can anyone explain how it is possible that UnderlyingType is evaluating to the first type, even when the template should be taking an int?  And possibly a solution?  I also tried replacing std::conditional_t with the implementation on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional thinking maybe it was some implementation quirk, but it seems to fail as well.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone that answered.  I was able to tweak the given answer a bit to allow only specified types.  Here's the full code for that for future googlers:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T> 
struct UnderlyingTypeStruct {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T> requires (!std::is_integral_v<T> && !std::is_enum_v<T>)
struct UnderlyingTypeStruct<T> {
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_enum_v<T>, "T must be an enum, or an integral type" ); 
    using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
};

template <typename T> requires std::is_integral_v<T>
struct UnderlyingTypeStruct<T> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T> requires std::is_enum_v<T>
struct UnderlyingTypeStruct<T> {
    using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
};

template<class T>
using UnderlyingType = typename UnderlyingTypeStruct<T>::type;

template< typename T >
constexpr UnderlyingType<T> toUnderlying( T val )
{
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_enum_v<T>, "T must be an enum, or an integral type" ); 
    return val;
}

enum ExampleEnum {
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

int main()
{
    UnderlyingType<ExampleEnum> underlying = toUnderlying( ZERO ); // ok
    std::cout << underlying << std::endl;
    UnderlyingType<ExampleEnum> actual = toUnderlying( 0 );  // okstd::cout << actual << std::endl;
    UnderlyingType<const char *> myInvalidString = toUnderlying( "hello world" ); // error
    std::cout << myInvalidString << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the link to an updated godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/KbbM3bdMj

Comment: the `true_type` must be valid even when it isnt choosen

Comment: You're thinking that `std::conditional_t` works on some kind of a short-circuit evaluations basis, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::conditional` doesnt even get to choose one of the types, because the first argument isnt a type. `std::underlying_type_t<int>` just doesnt exist. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type):

> If T is a complete enumeration (enum) type, provides a member typedef type that names the underlying type of T.
>
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. (until C++20)
>
> Otherwise, if T is not an enumeration type, there is no member type. Otherwise (T is an incomplete enumeration type), the program is ill-formed. (since C++20)

Wherher UB or not, there is no `std::underlying_type_t<int>`.

You can use SFINAE such that the specialization that does use `std::underlying_type_t<int>` gets discarded:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct UnderlyingType {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct UnderlyingType<T,std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>> {
    using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
};

template<class T>
using UnderlyingType_t = typename UnderlyingType<T>::type;

template< typename T >
constexpr UnderlyingType_t<T> toUnderlying( T val )
{
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_enum_v<T>, "T must be an enum, or an integral type" );
    return val;
}

enum ExampleEnum {
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};

int main()
{
    UnderlyingType_t<ExampleEnum> underlying = toUnderlying( ZERO ); // compiles and works fine
    UnderlyingType_t<ExampleEnum> actual = toUnderlying( 0 ); // error: no matching function for call to 'toUnderlying(int)'
}
```

Comment: Since OP tagged C++20, an alternative to `typename=void`/`std::enable_if_t` is to just put a `requires std::is_enum_v<T>` on the partial specialization. (That makes it also easier to understand.)

Comment: Your refactor seems to work, so thank you! ...though I'll admit I'm not really sure why... could you go into a bit more detail of how this sidesteps the type instantiation issue?  And what is typename = void doing in this code?  I've not seen a SFINAE example like this before.